# How I create a linq to xml query for binding xml to DropDownList with my structure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, file, drop-down-menu

hi i have a question to linq to xml ...

i have a xml file with Title value:

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Titles>
  <values id="de">
    <value value="Herr" display="Herr"></value>
    <value value="Frau" display="Frau"></value>
  </values>
  <values id="cs">
    <value value="Herr" display="Pan"></value>
    <value value="Frau" display="Paní"></value>
  </values>
  <values id="en">
    <value value="Herr" display="Mr."></value>
    <value value="Frau" display="Mrs."></value>
  </values>
  <values id="es">
    <value value="Herr" display="Sr."></value>
    <value value="Frau" display="Sra."></value>
  </values>
  <values id="zh">
    <value value="Herr" display="先生"></value>
    <value value="Frau" display="女士"></value>
  </values>
</Titles>
```

and I have a DropDownList:

```
<td><asp:DropDownList ID="drp_GuestListViewAddDialog_GuestTitle" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
```

here is my c# code:

```
 XDocument x = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\DropDown\Title.xml"));

                string data = (from item in x.Elements("Titles").Elements("values") where item.Attribute("id").Value == "de" select item.Attribute("display").Value).First();
```

UPDATE:

For Example if I want the id = "de" I want this

```
<values id="de">
    <value value="Herr" display="Herr"></value>
    <value value="Frau" display="Frau"></value>
  </values>
```

Comment: What is the `value` and the `text` you want in your dropdownlist? You need an `IEnumerable` to be your datasource, but you are selecting a single string.

Comment: with the "id" from "values" i want to filter and with values i want the "value" and the "display" attribute for set the attribute from the DropDownList: DataValueField and DataTextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: this works...

```
var x = XDocument.Load(@"~\App_Data\DropDown\Title.xml");
var list = x.Descendants("values")
    .Where(el => el.Attribute("id").Value == "de")
    .Descendants("value")
    .Select(el => new
    {
        value = el.Attribute("value").Value,
        display = el.Attribute("display").Value
    )
    .ToList();

drp_GuestListViewAddDialog_GuestTitle.DataValueField = "value";
drp_GuestListViewAddDialog_GuestTitle.DataTextField = "display";
drp_GuestListViewAddDialog_GuestTitle.DataSource = list;
drp_GuestListViewAddDialog_GuestTitle.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = doc.Descendants("values")
         .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("id") == "zh")
         .SelectMany(e => e.Elements("value"))
         .Select(v => new { Value = v.Attribute("value").Value, Text = v.Attribute("display").Value })
         .ToList();
```

Then bind it:

```
 drp_GuestListViewAddDialog_GuestTitle.Enabled = true;
 drp_GuestListViewAddDialog_GuestTitle.DataSource = result;
 drp_GuestListViewAddDialog_GuestTitle.DataBind();
```

Sorry, I can't check it to see if it compiles, I'm winging it here.